# Disabling DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I have a datepicker from [here](https://github.com/robzon/android-datepicker) that I have to enable and disable with a button click. I tried:

```
datepicker.setActivated(false);
datepicker.setEnabled(false);
datepicker.setClickable(false);
datepicker.setFocusable(false);
datepicker.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

but nothing works. I even tried putting the datepickerdialog inside a layout and put the same settings on the layout but didn't work as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, if you only set the `date picker.setEnabled(false);` the datepicker is still activated?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it. And, yes. Even with all of that set, it's still activated. Still enabled, clickable and focusable.

Comment: Why don't you use the standard android date picker as described here -http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: Actually what do you want to diable?? disable the keyboard when datepicker is clicked???

Comment: `datePicker.setDescendantFocusability(DatePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);` can be used to disable the keyboard in datepicker..

Comment: @Lai the whole link.

OH WAIT! is a datepicker far different from a datepickerdialog?

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated the whole question.

Comment: first of all do this `datepicker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` and check whether your datepicker gets invisible..@lei

Comment: I set toast on it's onclicklistener, and it was good. @lai

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you declare datepicker object globally bind this datepicker object inside  `onCreate()` using `findViewById()` method.

Comment: Yep, I have that. I even put a breakpoint on the part where it is set as not activated, and it ... how do I say that, successful? Lol.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to working this way. To disable the datepicker, select the date you want to display and

```
datePickerView.updateDate(year, month, day);
datePickerView.setMinDate(dateObject.getTime());
datePickerView.setMaxDate(dateObject.getTime());
```

To enable it back, set it accordingly to default or previous values.